# Puzzling UIImageView behavior in a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, properties, uiimageview, uiimage

I'm currently setting the UIImageView in my UITableViewCell like this:

```
// in cellForRowAtIndexPath method
[cell.imageView initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"]];
```

However the imageView property on UITableViewCell is `readonly`.  The code above works but **I don't understand why**.  **Any ideas**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't ever call `-init...` unless you're creating an object yourself. The cell creates its own image view (that's why it's read-only); you can simply set the image with `cell.imageView.image = [UIImage...];`.

Comment: It's probably just that `-[UIImageView initWithImage:]` doesn't check to see if it's already been initialized, and it has the behavior of setting the image. (You're not running into issues with the `readonly` qualifier because you're not trying to *set* the cell's image view — you're just sending it a message.) However it's never good practice to re-initialize an object.